# Is anyone able to run rust tests in VSCode when using a workspace?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode with a workspace specified in my `Cargo.toml`. I have embedded `#[test]` which show up in the editor window as a clickable `run test`. However, when I click VSCode attempts to run tests, but seems to not run any, having filtered it out. Has anyone managed to get embedded tests to work? With simpler projects, which don't have a workspace, I am able to get tests to run.

Comment: I have a workspace and can use the inline "run test" on my `#[test]` tests, so there must be more to the problem. I don't know what information would be useful to diagnose it, but I suggest starting with a file listing of your workspace, the `Cargo.toml` files for the workspace and the package within it, and the exact command and output from a test run attempt (copy the full text from the VS Code embedded terminal).

Comment: I may need to get vscode to pass the `--workspace` argument to cargo test command. Just need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, I just needed to convert my top-level `Cargo.toml` into a [Virtual Manifest](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#virtual-workspace). Once I did that, tests now run from the VSCode edit window.